# get list of profiles including the profile name using Amazon advertising API

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using amazon advertising API and want to get a list of profiles and let the user select the wanted profile from an HTML select elememt.

I can get list of profiles firing "GET" request to this URL:
https://advertising-api.amazon.com/v1/profiles
The problem is the response does not include the profile name.

Does anyone know if there's some way to get the profile name as well?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Hi @benjah, I am currently developing an app that uses advertising api. I help help and My question is, how do you able to make /profiles working ? I am stucked for several days and pointless how to get the profiles. It always return empty. The sandbox works fine. I already tested the app to be authorize by a real seller using LWA

Comment: Hey @rai, we actually ended up withdraw from this project as Amazon's advertising API was very poor and missing a lot of important data so it couldn't answer our needs. 
Sorry that I can't help, hopefully, Amazon will get this API better in the future... (it was about 4 years ago, I thought they already did but apparently they didn't).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as a "name" property does not exist. An alternative is to instead show a list of marketplace regions. e.g. NA, EU, etc.